# HTML or XML Parser Using JSP

Tags: jsp, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I am developing JSP Search Engine i want to parse html page using **it's Link** and search for some Words in it 
Thanks

Comment: Do not write any logic in JSPs. These are intended for views only.

Comment: how can i parse html to title and body  to get the words which i searched for

Comment: @Michael-O  there is logic package on it

Answer (score 0):

For parsing html(only xhtml) or xml you can use xslt processors (Saxon, MSxsl). You can generate another xml, html or text file using xsl stylesheet.

Comment: [saxonica](http://www.saxonica.com) here you can read about Saxon. There is installation for Java platform and .NET platform. Try xslt online [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) or something similar. Do not use an XML parser. There is no guarantee that every web page is XML compliant.